# iPhone:Can i run two timer at a time?

Tags: iphone, nstimer

My game program is running two timers at a time. For showing timer logic and game logic. As far as now, no problems. Both seems to be working fine. Can it be there or will it create any problems or crash at any point of time? When i want to stop the timers at a time, can i just 'invalidate' both timers at a time? Does anyone has suggestion on this?

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to create as many timers as you need and invalidate any of them as needed.